# Installed program not listed In Programs and Features

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, control-panel, addremoveprograms

I'm using Inno Setup 5.5.6 to create an install file. Everything works fine and gets installed except the Program is not listed in the ***Program and Features*** section of the **Control Panel**.

What would cause this to happen and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry in Control Panel is not added, if the installer is set not to be uninstallable at all using [`Uninstallable` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable):

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=no
```

Or if the creation of the entry is simply turned off using [`CreateUninstallRegKey` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey):

```
[Setup]
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
```

---

Check if a respective registry entry is created:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AppId_is1]
```

Comment: CreateUninstallRegKey was set to no. Thank you.

Comment: In my case, all 3 points are fine. The problem comes that inno detects a fail at install (while installing vcredist). But everthing is installed at it's place (registry too) and well running. Windows manages something else to create this list?

Comment: @Sandburg Consider posting a new question. Include installer log file.